# Data migration from SAP to MySql

Tags: excel, mysql-workbench, abap

I just want my whole data in the SAP ABAP to be created in the MySql Workbench along with the table structure as a new database. I find phpmyadmin is not working for me. Also tried to download the data from SAP as excel and then use that excel sheet to create data using the existing table by the usage of load data local infinite but i find the chunk data are being also appended to the table. is there any other possibility to achieve the intended.

Comment: I can't think of any valid reason for this - why would you want to do that?

Comment: the application i'm going to develop has same structure of the data requirement of past which had its data in SAP. the new application should not depend on any middle-ware

Comment: I hope you are only copying over custom tables (starting with Z or Y), blatantly copying SAP tables opens a whole can of legal worms.

Comment: My two cents, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041871/how-to-import-sql-server-table-to-sap-abap-itab/15165487#15165487

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, which dumps the contents of the tables in the ABAP dictionary to an SQL file which you can import to MySQL:  http://www.stschnell.de/sapdataexport.htm

(EDIT: Sorry, if you read the page linked above, you will see of course that it references specifically SQLite, but mentions that the export can be used as an import to other databases).

You should also be aware that the ABAP dictionary does not necessarily contain references to *all* tables in the database, such as a few system tables etc, but I'm guessing for your purposes that does not matter.

Even better would be if you had DBA access to the database, then you can just dump everything from there rather than going via ABAP.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i dont know abc of sap can you pls make it simpler for me to understand

Comment: Based on the comments above, I suggest you speak to whoever is in charge to provide you someone with SAP knowledge, or maybe the DBA. That is all I can recommend.