# How to import SQL Server table to itab?

Tags: sql-server, abap, opensql, internal-tables

is it possible to import data in SQL Server table to internal table (itab) directly?

I want to use this itab in a SE37 function. thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. No. Perhaps. Maybe, maybe not. Could you give us a clearer picture of what you want to do and what you have already tried and researched?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <transparent_table> INTO TABLE <internal_table>`? But then you have to be really sure that this database table is really small and does not contain too many records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your task you can use a function module (SE37) or you can use module pool, or a report (SE38, SE80). Check this report:

```
report zinsertdb.

data: oref   type ref to cx_root,
      p_conex type dbcon_name value 'YOUR_DB_CONNECTION_STRING', " Ask the basis for this
      lv_sw type c,
      errormessage type string.

data it_mydata type standard table of mara.

start-of-selection.

  perform connect.
  perform insert_into_db.
  perform disconnect.

form connect.
  try.
      EXEC SQL.
        CONNECT TO :p_conex
      ENDEXEC.
      lv_sw = 'X'.
    catch cx_sy_native_sql_error into oref.
      lv_sw = space.
      errormessage = oref->get_text( ).
  endtry.
endform.

form disconnect.
  clear errormessage.
  if lv_sw = 'X'.
    try.
        EXEC SQL.
          COMMIT
        ENDEXEC.
      catch cx_sy_native_sql_error into oref.
        errormessage = oref->get_text( ).     
    endtry.
  endif.
endform.

form insert_into_db.

   data wa_mydata like line of it_mydata.
   data zcount type i.

   select * from mara into corresponding fields of table it_mydata.

   if sy-subrc EQ 0.

     loop at it_mydata into wa_mydata.

        try .

            exec sql. 
              EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_get_data ( IN :wa_mydata-EAN11, IN :wa_mydata-MEINS, OUT :zcount ) 
            endexec.

            if zcount eq 0.
              exec sql.
                INSERT INTO "Your_Database".dbo.[Your_table]
                (Field1, Field2, Field3, FieldN)
                 VALUES (:wa_mydata-matnr,
                         :wa_mydata-ean11,
                         :wa_mydata-matkl,
                         :wa_mydata-meins)
              endexec.
              lv_sw = 'X'.
            endif.

          catch cx_sy_native_sql_error into oref.
            lv_sw = space.
            errormessage = oref->get_text( ).   
        endtry.

     endloop.

   endif.

endform.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want to do. I'm assuming what you mean is that you'd like to read an entire SQL table (or certain entries from it) into program memory? Perhaps you could shed some more light here?

If that's the case than you can simply declare an internal table which has the structure of your SQL table containing the data.

`DATA: table_name TYPE STANDARD/HASHED/SORTED TABLE OF name_of_sql_table.`

`FIELD-SYMBOLS <structure> TYPE name_of_sql_table.`

`SELECT * FROM name_of_sql_table INTO TABLE table_name.`

And from there it's just reading data from the internal table.

`READ TABLE table_name ASSIGNING <structure> WITH KEY table_key_field(s) = condition(s).`

But as jagger said be careful how big your table is.