# How to update SAP database from Asp.net App

Tags: sap-basis

I have a asp.net web app and i want to update SAP whenever a particular transaction happens with my asp.net app. I want to know if any SAP API or Web Service available from SAP using which i can update SAP .

If anyone knows it plz let me know.

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you are trying to do.  There are several ways to update SAP, but it depends on which objects you are trying to update.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can talk only for R/3 but I'll make my best shot.

You can make inserts, updates and deletes to SAP tables through IDOCs, webservices, 3rd party SAP Connectors and intermediate tables.

An IDOC is an SAP standard document format for data interchange with other systems. This process is known as Inbound/Outbound in SAP and basically is a common interface where SAP and other systems share files with a established structure. In our company for example we comunicate with a satellite system sending XML files where SAP first takes the IDOCs and transform them before sending. Another case is where a system place text files in a carpet through FTP and SAP takes and transforms them to IDOCs to consume and extract the data to update the system.

However this configuration is very complex and requires study, analysis and experience to make this works fine. For deep insight I recommend you to visit http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp2005/helpdata/en/0b/2a60bb507d11d18ee90000e8366fc2/frameset.htm.

For webservices it is needed Netweaver integration (Web Services based) where you can manage this service, but basically you can program a web service  with the Web Application Builder with transaction SE80.

The other thing you can use is a .Net Connector where you can integrate with .Net the RFC calls of SAP function modules. You can check an example with a SAP .Net Connector [here](http://rfcconnector.com/documentation/examples/client/) for more information.

Finally a technique that would be helpful is to create intermediate tables in a database where your system and SAP can communicate. The approach consists in creating custom tables where your program adds data and SAP reads it making connection to the database. To make a connection to a database you can check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041871/how-to-import-sql-server-table-to-sap-abap-itab).

As I stated before I just can talk for SAP R/3 to share data but I can't talk for SAP Business One.

Hope it helps.