# SAP Crystal reports SAP R3 to .NET

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, sap-r3

I am trying to create an SAP Crystal report on Visual Studio 2012. I have installed the same on VS and can now open the report in a WinForm application. I am basically looking to get SAP R/3 data (maybe through an RFC) and display it on the report.

Presently, I am not getting the SAP option under the "Database Expert" for the Crystal report.

Can anyone tell me the correct way of migrating data from SAP R/3 and displaying it on the crystal report?

Comment: trying to get a SAP stackexchange started for questions just like this. Check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Comment: My two cents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082836/how-to-update-sap-db-from-asp-net-app/15228900#15228900

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, you can't directly access data from a SAP ERP system like a database. You will need to connect to the SAP System using a connector (for instance the SAP .Net Connector, download [here](http://service.sap.com/connectors) (you will need access to the SAP Service portal). Using the .Net Connector you can either use BAPIs to access business objects or use remote enabled function modules like RFC_READ_TABLE to load table contents. After that you can put these information for instance in a dataset and use that in crystal reports.