# Insert single into DB table by not using structure as data holder

Tags: abap

Is there a way to insert single record in db table without using structure as data holder.

I was thinking something like

```
INSERT INTO table(filed1, field2) VALUES (value1, value2).
```

Is something like this possible in abap? thx

Comment: I think that is possible, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041871/how-to-import-sql-server-table-to-sap-abap-itab/15165487#15165487)

Comment: @NelsonMiranda Rule 1: Never use Native SQL unless you need it. Rule 2: You don't need Native SQL unless you're coding DB management / DDIC stuff.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: @vwegert I'll take it in consideration. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible because you can't specify individual target fields with [OpenSQL INSERT statements](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapinsert_dbtab.htm). You might be able to work around the need for a temporary structure on the right-hand side by using a [`VALUE type( ... )`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenconstructor_expression_value.htm) operator, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I've tried it and it's not possible to specify a temporary structure in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a structure dynamically.

using `CL_ABAP_STRUCTDESCR=>CREATE`, specifying a list of components (list of column) and their types, you get dynamically a description of your structure that you can use to create a data reference.

Quick pseudo-code:

```
DATA coldescr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.
DATA cols TYPE REF TO data.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <cols> TYPE any.

coldescr = cl_abap_structdescr=>create(  ).

CREATE DATA cols TYPE HANDLE coldescr.

ASSIGN cols->* TO <cols>.
```

You can use `<cols>` in you insert select stmt.